# Find the slice cut by a line segment, an origin point on a 3D polygon

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, 3d, polygon, line-segment

I have an array of triangle vertices (faces of the polygon), something like

```
[[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]], ...]
```

I have a line segment, represented by 2 3D vertices, let's say `[[j, k, l], [m, n, o]]`.

And I have a point `[p, q, r]`.

What I want to do is, project the point on the polygon, through the line segment, and check if it completely slices the polygon (I think 4 points of contact should be enough? I could be wrong). And if it does, I need all the points of intersection which lie on the edges and vertices.

I'm completely lost here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Polygons are 2D. Polyhedra require a plane in order to be cut.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Didn't know it was called a polyhedron. Thanks! What do you mean by "require a plane"?

Comment: A line cannot slice a polyhedron; it doesn't have enough dimensions.

Comment: Yeah, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a point and a line segment be enough? The plane would could be considered  a ray from the point to every point of the line segment. Wouldn't that construct an infinite plane? And be enough for slicing?

Comment: Okay, I see what the question is asking now. But there will be an infinite number of points of intersection; perhaps you should restrict the requirement to points of intersection at edges and vertices.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I want the points of intersection at edges and vertices. Corrected the question.

Comment: Why would 4 points of contact be enough? Since the triangle formed from your point+line segment defines only part of a plane, then it's very possible that there would be 4 POI or more, but the triangle doesn't "completely slice the polygon", but rather cuts part of it.

Answer (score 1):

We can assume without loss of generality that the triangle formed by the point & line segment (henceforth T) lies in the x-y plane. (Otherwise, rotate everything appropriately).

We loop through the triangle faces, for any pair of vertices of a face where their y-coordinates have different signs (i.e. for any edge that cuts the x-y plane), we check the intersection of the edge with the x-y plane and make sure it's within T.

It holds that T "completely slices the polygon" if and only if all such checks are true.

Running time is `O(number of faces)`.

All the operations described are pretty simple. E.g. Checking that something is in the bounds of T is simply checking two inequalities with the equations of the two lines that define T (i.e. from the point to the end points of the line segment).

All POI with the edges (and thus vertices) can be calculated within the loop - it's simply the POI of the edge with the x-y plane.